# Make player movement consistent with touch controls?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Currently I'm using this code for player movement for my very basic mobile game.

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {

            //Animation

            animator.SetBool("Is Moving", true);

            //Left click
            var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if (touch.position.x < Screen.width / 2)
            {
                transform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * speed;
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.up * 180); //Sets rotation of character
            }

            //Right Click
            else if (touch.position.x > Screen.width / 2)
            {
                transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * speed;
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.up * 0); //Sets rotation of character
            }

            if (Input.touchCount > 1 && !isJumping)
            {
                transform.position += new Vector3(0, 5, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
                isJumping = true;
            }
         }
```

The problem I'm faced with is this: currently, when touching with more than 1 finger, sometimes the player will move in the direction of the later finger to be touched down, and sometimes it doesn't (so if I'm holding down left, and then hold down right, sometimes the player will continue to move left, sometimes the player will instead move right).

I'm not sure what is causing the inconsistency, any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: In the worst case you could keep track of touches yourself and, when the touchCount increases, consider the furthest touch from the existing touch points to be the new touch.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of that last known direction using an enum, and if if at any point there are no touches set it to none. If at anypoint you have a left and right touch you can resort to the last known direction if it is not none.